# How to load CSV in a workbook replacing existing sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Macro which imports a CSV-file as a new sheet which is called "Tickets". When this file aready exists, I get a runtime-error. Is there a way to just overwrite the existing file if it already exists?

```
Sub GetCSVList()
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    ''Start in
    .InitialFileName = "C:\test"
    .Show
End With

For Each fname In dlgOpen.SelectedItems
    ImportCSV fname
Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ImportCSV(fname)
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Tickets"


With ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Test" & Worksheets.Count + 1
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    '.UseListObject = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not saving any files so there's nothing to overwrite. Where exactly is the error occurring? When you're opening the file due to another file already being open with the same name? Or when trying to rename the worksheet because there's already a worksheet called Tickets?

Comment: When I open the Macro, it creates a new worksheet with the CSV-Data inside which is named "Tickets". When I get an update of the CSV-file, I open the Macro again and it tells me "Runtime Error '1004: This name is already in use. Please select another one". So I would like to overwrite the existing worksheet or the data inside it and insert the new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a new worksheet at the end, try to delete any existing worksheet named "Tickets" before renaming the new worksheet to "Tickets":

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Tickets").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

On Error Resume Next will ignore the error that would arise if there aren't any existing worksheets named "Tickets". This is a little lazy, but that's pretty much the only error that will arise from the Worksheet.Delete method, so you can get away it.

Do not "On Error Resume Next" to just ignore other types of errors in programming!

Comment: Another thing: the CSV-Source File alsways has the same name in the same directory. Do you know how I can edit this macro that it always automatically loads a CSV-file in a specific folder instead of the popup where I have to select the CSV? Thank you!!

Comment: Just call ImportCSV(filename) directly, specifying the filename as a string. E.g. ImportCSV("C:\test.csv")